# Use of Mann-Whitney w/ Ties

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ties

I am tracking the results of a test between a control group and 1 variant group. Each group contains (an unequal quantity of) users whose order count we're now tracking. The histogram is heavily weighted toward 1 order for both groups, so not normally distributed.

If it were, I'd just want to run a t-test to see if the variant group places more orders on average than the control. Based on some research, it seems like the M-W test is best to answer this, but I just want to confirm that the "ties" I have aren't going to skew the result - I've seen some contradictory info. I've calculated using wilcox.test in R.

I also looked at a chi-squared test, but it didn't seem to be the right format for my dataset.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Implementations of the nonparametric Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon two-sample test differ from one software program to another. If sample sizes are large, most programs use a normal approximation of the test statistic and a modest number of ties is not a problem. For small sample sizes, the exact distribution of the rank-based test statistic is not known if there are ties. // So in order to give a useful answer I'd need to know your sample sizes and see some examples showing the frequency of ties.

Comment: Have a look at the packages `exactRankTests` and `coin` on CRAN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my Comment, the answer depends on sample sizes and frequency of ties.
Here are a couple of examples in R.

**Example 1.**  Small samples, many ties:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4)
y = c(5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6)

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   3.000   2.714   3.500   4.000 
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.000   4.000   5.000   4.571   5.000   6.000
```

A stripchart (dotplot) of the data seems to show larger values for the `y`s (top).

```
stripchart(list(x,y), ylim=c(.5,2.6), pch=20, meth="stack")
```

[image]

In R, the P-value of `wilcox.test` shows a P-value below 5%, hinting at a significant difference, but then a warning message puts the P-value in doubt.

```
wilcox.test(x, y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 5, p-value = 0.01314
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x, y) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Not as a formal test, but to get an idea how serious the ties really are.
one can explore 'jittering' the data (introducing small amounts of random
noise) to break the ties.

```
set.seed(1234)
x.j = x + runif(7, -0.01, 0.01)
y.j = y + runif(7, -0.01, 0.01)
wilcox.test(x.j, y.j)$p.value
[1] 0.004079254
x.j = x + runif(7, -0.01, 0.01)
y.j = y + runif(7, -0.01, 0.01)
wilcox.test(x.j, y.j)$p.value
[1] 0.01748252
x.j = x + runif(7, -0.01, 0.01)
y.j = y + runif(7, -0.01, 0.01)
wilcox.test(x.j, y.j)$p.value
[1] 0.006993007
```

Various ways of artificially breaking ties all gave significant results.
So maybe it is worthwhile doing a permutation test. Perhaps using the
the pooled t statistic $T$ as the metric. We are not claiming that the data are normal or that the t statistic
has Student's t distribution; only that data are numeric and that the t.statistic
is a reasonable measure of the differences between the samples. [In R the
code `sample(g)` randomly permutes assignments to the two groups (y in each group).]

```
w = c(x,y);  g = c(rep(1,7), rep(2,7))
t.obs = t.test(w~g, var.eq=T)$stat;  t.obs
      t 
-3.3199 
set.seed(2021)
t.prm = replicate(10^4, t.test(w~sample(g),var.eq=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) >= abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.0162   $ P-value of permutation test
```

Thus we can reject the null hypothesis that the two groups are the same
with P-value about 0.016.$

Among the 10,000 permutations of sample between groups, there were 22 uniquely
different values of the metric $T$ and the permutation distribution is estimated
by the histogram below. [For such small samples, some moderately tedious combinatorial computations could be used to find the exact permutation distribution, but the simulated distribution is close enough.] The P-value of the permutation test is the fraction
of values of `t.prm` at or more extreme than the vertical red bars.

```
 hdr = "Permutation Dist'n of Metric"
 hist(t.prm, prob=T, col="skyblue2");  rug(t.prm)
  abline(v = c(-t.obs, t.obs), col="red")
```

[image]

**Example 2:**  Large samples, many ties.

```
set.seed(329)
x = rpois(100, 5)
y = rpois(100, 7)
```

Among the 200 observations overall, there are only $11+12 = 23$ uniquely
different values:

```
length(unique(x));  length(unique(y))
[1] 11
[1] 12
```

Boxplots show clear differences in medians. The 'notches' in the sides of the
boxes are nonparametric confidence intervals. They are calibrated so that
non-overlapping CIs in two plots indicates that medians differ.

```
boxplot(x, y, col="skyblue2", pch=19, notch=T)
```

[image]

A Wilcoxon test in R, gives a highly significant P-value (almost $0)$ with no warnings
about ties.

```
wilcox.test(x,y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 3079.5, p-value = 2.178e-06
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Hi Bruce - This is fantastic! Thank you so much for providing such detail. We've run this test on a few different sets of users. Within each set, between the control and variant, I have ~200-300 users with only 9 or 10 unique values, so I believe it falls under your example 2. I didn't get any warning about ties when running in R. However, I ran a boxplot on one set and the medians are basically the same. Based on your response, and Bernhard's comment above, do you think it requires permutation testing? Or is the original M-W significant p-value safe? Thanks so much!

Comment: If Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon shows a significant diff and gives no warnings, I wouldn't do a permutation. test. (In a sense, MWW is a sort of 'frozen' perm. test with no choice of metric.) // If you have only 9 or 10 unique values, it's not surprising to see same sample medians in both groups: there aren't very many possible medians. // MWW works best if _shapes_ of the two samples are similar so it can function as a test of shift of location. (Wouldn't use it if one sample skewed left, the other right.) Otherwise, MWW is test of stochastic dominance, which is not always intuitive to visualize.

Comment: Ok, fantastic. In this case, the shapes are similar so it sounds like I'm good to go w/ MWW. This has been incredibly helpful. Thanks so very much!